# npm pkg timeout issue

Tags: npm, exe

Now I have implemented automated testing with a puppeteer and I have packaged it and executed it.
However, after six hours, I found that the file packaged in a pkg was not running and stopped.
I used "npm pkg" to package.
Is there anyone who is talking about this issue?

add comment
:https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg. I installed the npm pkg module after seeing this place.
I'm in the process of automated testing of a website with a puppeteer and it took me more than six hours to spin the executable file to run the test on this website.
We executed exe file by packaging code written with puppeteer using 'pkg' module.
I had a screenshot of the execution process because I was testing the website, and after six hours, I found that the screenshot was not being taken from a certain point in time.
I have already completed the unit test of my code, so I judged that there was a problem with the pkg file, not with my code or with the website.

my try:
I was setting the option for reload to waitUntil:networkidle0 I think this option is the problem. I set networkidle0 to networkidle2, and it works well. Is there anyone who knows about the difference in this?

Comment: You might have to provide more details. Were there any logs that you can share? Is there code you can share? How did you run your code, how did you know it stopped?

Comment: First of all, I'm sorry I didn't write down the details.If you have time, please read the comments I added.